# const variable initialization inside lock

Tags: c, linux, locking, mutex, race-condition

I need to protect the assignment or initialization of a const variable using lock. Something like this:

```
int device_write() {
/* ... */
lock (lock);
const int var = test_variable[INDEX];
/* ... */


...
/* var being used here sometime later*/

unlock(lock)
...
}
```

But now the compiler starts giving warning that declaration is after statement. Becasue the `const int var = ..` declaration is below spin_lock().

The `var` variable is not a global variable.

Actually the Right hand side of assignment is pretty big in real code. So want to capture that first in variable named var and use it later in a complex statement involving var with various bit operation. That is the requirement. Cant change that

Basically on the right hand side of the assignment the `test_variable[..]` is vulnerable to race condition due to concurrency/multithreading. Hence a lock() is needed for protection.
Is there any other elegant way around to achieve that?

Comment: You could put the entire code between `lock` and `unlock` in a new scope, by enclosing it in `{ ... }` braces.

Comment: Ah yes, with the [mre] you provided I can see that now. You might want to work on it a little more to get it compilable.

Comment: Now I wonder WHY you want to do that, why you think it necessary. Please explain. What could possibly go wrong if that initialisation of a local variable (it still is not a write access you know) was not protected? Could demonstrate what other context is potentially running and accessing that test_variable?

Comment: @Yunnosch. Nice point. Actually the Right hand side of assignment is pretty big  in real code. So want to capture that first in variable named var and use it later in a complex statement involving var with various bit operation. That is the requirement. Cant change that

Comment: Rather that showing us pseudocode  (i.e. `lock ( ...)`) show us some *real* code that exhibits the problem you're experiencing.  We can't tell you what the compiler's complaining about unless we know **exactly** what you gave it.

Comment: @dbush. The pseudo code that I gave in question is almost similar to real code. Actually I cant share the real code. Please give your best shot by looking at the pseudo code.

Comment: @NeedSomeLuck Pseudocode is **useless** when it comes to compiler warnings/errors.  Either update the question with a [mcve] that others can use to see your issue or the question will be closed due to lack of information.

Comment: Give me more time to edit the question so that it becomes almost identical to the real code.

Comment: @NeedSomeLuck it doesn't have to be your actual production code.  It only has to be a small piece that when compiled has the same issue as the real code.  That the "minimal" in MRE.

Comment: @dbush. OK I have modified the question.

Comment: @AdrianMole I now realise (because of a comment on my anser by OP) that I have unknowingly turned your comment into an answer. I simply did not see it (a comment I otherwise do not like reading myself...). I just wanted to notify you. Please let me know whether you mind.

Comment: @Yunnosch Not a problem! But I appreciate your notification - good old fashioned decency is always welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to separate the definition of the variable from the write access that needs protection, especially as the part which writes to the left (by your own statement) is not the point.
To make sure that the variable does not get a value from an inconsistent read, it is enough to do the reading inside the lock, which in turn does not need to be at initialisation, which was what annoyed the compiler.

So:

```
int some_function()
{
    /* ... */
    int nonconst = 0; /* no declaration is after statement */
    lock ( ...)
    nonconst = test_variable[INDEX]; /* only assignment, no declaration */
    /* ... */

    { /* start a new block to solve the compilers sequence complaint */
        const int var = nonconst; /* var itself is const */

      /* ... */
      /* var being used sometime later, no code can change var */
      /* changing the nonconst variable is possible, but does not affect
         the value of var anymore */
      /* ... */
    }
    unlock(...)
}
```

Above is my answer, please find below a more elegant version, which I understand was derived by OP from the insightful comment of Adrian Mole (which I blindly missed...) and the structure of my answer. Should Adrian or OP make their own answer and notify me, I will delete this part. For the time being it improves this answer, for the benefit of others.

```
int some_function()
{
    /* ... */
    lock ( ...);

    { /* start a new block to solve the compilers sequence complaint */
        const int var = test_variable[INDEX]; /* var itself is const */

      /* ... */
      /* var being used sometime later, no code can change var */
      /* ... */
    }
    unlock(...);
}
```

I did some tiny edits to reduce confusion and compiler warnings a little.

Comment: But by doing this, the variable is becoming non-const - Cant do that. The variable has to remain constant.

Comment: Ah OK .. got it

Comment: I am happy to discuss which parts need protecting, but I think this covers your needs.

Comment: Your answer is great ... Just want to point out it can be done without creating a new variable nonconst. Isn't it ?

Comment: @NeedSomeLuck Show that in an explained answer and I will happily upvote it. (no sarcasm intended, happy to learn and applaude)

Comment: Or are you *asking* whether it can be done without an additional variable? In that case lets wait for other answers.

Comment: :) Please check this and let me know: https://ideone.com/FU1jDI

Comment: Yes I meant it can be done without an additional variable :)

Comment: Nice, I would consider it fair for you to make your own answer like that (noting that it is based on mine). It is a nicely more elegant way, worth my upvote. Alternatively, I will incorporate your input into my answer.

Comment: This was mentioned in topmost comment - the comments after my question, but I think you can incorporate it in your answer if you want :) Actually I am just waiting if someone else might have some other solution. Will wait for few more hours.

Comment: Oh shoot. I did not realise the meaning of that comment, before you pointed it out... Blind me. Going to ask forgiving...